# How to give appended elements a position with jQuery

Tags: jquery, append, position, element

my appended elements are very messy and all over the place.
When you append something in one box, the other ones move.

My question to you is;
How can i give some kind of structure to the elements i'm appending. 
Maybe with some sort of tile strategy?

i want exactly 4 boxes next to each other and the fifth beneath it so you create rows of 4.
but i dont know how to do this and if its a lot of work

here is my code: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Es3R9/

Comment: Sounds like a CSS issue to me! The DOM elements you want next to each other should be siblings inside the same parent node. `appendTo(".container")` seems right to me. You may want to store a reference to the jQuery object, so that jQuery does not need to search the entire DOM tree for the container every time you want to append something to it.

Comment: @aftEkenholm thank you that makes sense! What do you mean with store a reference if i may ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the width of your container to `800px` and add `float: left;` to `.redbox`. That's it.

Comment: Thank you that does work! Nice simple solution :) Do you know how i can prevent the box beneath another to jump to the right when you append in the box above it?

Comment: I can't follow you. Post another question with an example.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Aaron! I'll try it myself first! ;)